# How to remove RSS feeds from Wordpress theme

Tags: rss

I am a newbie at WordPress and wanted to know if their is a way to remove RSS notifications from the theme I am using. I tried looking for a functions.php file but have not had any luck. I am using the Opulus Sombre theme.

Answer (score 3):

I never used the theme "Opulus Sombre". But the feed link on the `<head>` section typically comes from the `functions.php`. There is a line saying<sup>1</sup>:

```
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links'  );
```

Otherwise it can be hard-coded to your `header.php` like<sup>2</sup>:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
```

<sub>1. Codex: [Automatic Feed Links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Automatic_Feed_Links)

2. [WordPress 3.0 Theme Tip Feed Links — ottopress.com](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-theme-tip-feed-links/)</sub>

### EDIT

Thanks to Chip Bennett for the actual answer, just putting that into the answer with full respect to him:
Just use the following code into your `functions.php` to remove feed link:

```
add_action( 'after_theme_support', 'wpse_122841_remove_feed' );

function wpse_122841_remove_feed() {
   remove_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
}
```

Thanks to Chip Bennett for the addition. Thanks birgire and Vincent for suggesting the fixes.

Comment: +1. Use `remove_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' )`, in a callback hooked into `after_theme_support`, to remove.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of `remove_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' )`.

Comment: I would also suggest prefixing the function name to avoid possible name collision.